# How to debug the error in developing a slider to scroll through all the images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing this slider, but it does not run through all the images when I click the "next" (>) or "previous" (<) button. (It run only once)
My intention is that the slider goes to the last image by clicking the (>) button (one by one) and when you click back (<) it can return the previous images (one by one). Thank you!

JSField: https://jsfiddle.net/silvio7d/7gpo9485/

HTML

```
<!-- wrapperAll -->
<section class="wrapperAll">

    <section class="sliderComplete">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <section class="wrapper">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/packshot/pdp-reco-2x/W0/21/2C/00/CQ/11/W0212C00C-Q11@12.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">EXO - 'MAMA' Mix</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">BMixer</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">Galaxy Supernova</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">GG</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">2nd Album</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Boyfriend</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/packshot/pdp-reco-2x/W0/21/2C/00/CQ/11/W0212C00C-Q11@12.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">3</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Indochine</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">Nadiya</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Nadiya</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">OBJETOS</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">30% OFF*</a></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">OBJETOS</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">30% OFF*</a></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">OBJETOS</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">30% OFF*</a></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="cover">
                        <img src="https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/ER/75/2L/00/1D/11/ER752L001-D11@7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    <p><a href="#">OBJETOS</a> - Extra</p>
                    <p><a href="#">30% OFF*</a></p>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </section>

        <button title="before" class="close">
            <svg version="1.1" id="left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                 viewBox="12.7 2.5 15.4 25" enable-background="new 12.7 2.5 15.4 25" height="24" xml:space="preserve">
            <g id="chevron-right">
                <polygon fill="#38373A" points="13,15 25,27 27.8,24.2 18.6,15 27.8,5.8 25,3     "/>
            </g>
            </svg>
        </button>


        <button title="after" class="open">
            <svg version="1.1" id="right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                 viewBox="12.7 2.5 15.4 25" enable-background="new 12.7 2.5 15.4 25" height="24" xml:space="preserve">
            <g id="chevron-right">
                <polygon fill="#38373A" points="15.8,3 13,5.8 22.2,15 13,24.2 15.8,27 27.8,15   "/>
            </g>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </section>
    <!-- End sliderComplete -->
</section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.sliderComplete').children('button').removeClass('close').fadeIn(500);

        $(this).addClass('close').fadeOut(500);

        $(this).parents('.sliderComplete').children('.wrapper').children('.slider').toggleClass('turn');
    });
});
```

Comment: Call event within the functions call. Like this - function(event) {...}

Comment: Please add your html and make a snippet if you know how to. I can help if you don’t.